# How to automatically add tags to plain text data?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

i'm making a recipe database, but i want a table for ingredients and for actions (i.e whisk) and when a user submits the plain text instructions i want it to wrap those keywords with div tags.

is there a similar app that does something like that?

Comment: what website are u building ?

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: i'm building a recipe writing site.

Comment: i'm trying to find words in an array and wrap those words in html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$text = 'this is a cooking test';

$keywords = array('cooking' => array('before' => '<span class="cooking">', 'after' => '</span>'));

foreach($keywords as $key => $value) {
    $text = str_replace($key, $value['before'].$key.$value['after'], $text);
}
print $text;
```

this would produce:

```
this is a <span class="cooking">cooking</span> test
```